# What is RecyclerView.Adapter's equivalent for ArrayAdapter's getView method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I'm in the process of converting a `ScrollView` to a `RecyclerView`. In one of my methods, I have declared this originally:

`View item = listAdapter.getView(i, null, (ViewGroup) template);`

`listAdapter` is originally an `ArrayAdapter`, but I wrote a new `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and it is now declared as such. I was wondering how I would rewrite the statement above since `RecyclerView.Adapter` doesn't have a `getView` method.

Comment: Check my proposed answer below, I hope it helps. If yes please click the green check mark. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **RecyclerView**, it is different, you manage all the data in the **RecyclerView.Adapter** Class:

If you wrote a **RecyclerView.Adapter** with a **ViewHolder**, you can have the **getView** into the **RecyclerView.Adapter** Class you wrote.
it is in the **onBindViewHolder** method

you just have to call it this way:

```
holder.itemView
```

Here is a **RecyclerViewAdapter** class I wrote as an example, showing how to call the **itemView** in **onBindViewHolder**
I assigned a **onItemClickListener** to the **itemView**, and I also have 2 **TextViews** (declared in the **ViewHolder** at the bottom)

```
        public class SampleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
            private ArrayList<Order> orderList;
            private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
            private Context context;

        public SampleRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Order> orderList) {
            this.orderList = orderList;
            this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public SampleRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_order, parent, false);
            return new SampleRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final SampleRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Order order = orderList.get(position);
            holder.date.setText(order.getFormattedDate()+", "+ order.getFormattedTime());
            holder.orderNumber.setText(order.getUid());

    //Here, calling itemView (equivalent of listAdapter.getView()) and setting a onClickListener as an example. You can do whatever you want.
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, OrderDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("order", order);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return orderList.size();
        }

  //In the ViewHolder you declare all the components of your xml layout for you recyclerView items ( and the data is assigned in the onBindViewHolder, above)  
        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView date, orderNumber;

            private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
                orderNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOrderNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```